# What to do with questions that you have "given up on"?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I used to have a problem with Firefox portable but for various reasons decided not to use it. So now what should I do regarding answers to [this question?](https://superuser.com/questions/700666/how-to-open-regular-firefox-after-firefox-portable-has-been-open/880337#880337) I can't test any of them as I don't have portable anymore so how can I accept the right one?

Comment: You don't need to do anything. You could wait for someone to come along and upvote one saying it worked, or it could live out in limbo until someone else answers it. You could also convert it to a wiki to disown it.